# Executing a package manager command on just one project in a solution

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wcf

I have two projects in my solution, one is a WPF application and the other is a WCF.

I have entity framework on my WCF application and want to execute the Update-Database command since I have added to my initial seed method. How can I run this on the WCF project alone? As of now I get a warning telling me that migrations are not enabled for my WPF project.

Answer (score 1):

You may also select the project in the "Default project:" `ComboBox` in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, Target a project like so:

```
Update-Database -ProjectName MyProjectName
```